# Getting an invalidcastexception when trying to retrieve data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core

When running the get method to return a view populated with details, I get the exception saying:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.DateTime'.'
```

The code code that does it is this:

```
 public IActionResult GetBookings()
    {
        List<Booking> list = new List<Booking>();

        foreach(var b in _airPortContext.Booking) // <--- Exceptions comes on this line
        {                
            list.Add(b);
        }

        return View(list);
    }
```

I am not sure why it's trying to cast the object to a date type

My model looks like this:

```
    public class Booking
{
    public int BookingID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Class type")]
    public int ClassLevel { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "From")]
    public string FromDestination { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "To")]
    public string ToDestination { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "From date")]
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "To date")]
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Class")]
    public ClassType TravelClass { get; set; }              
}
```

------------------Update------------------

```
       protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .UseIdentityColumns()
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128)
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "5.0.0");

            modelBuilder.Entity("Airport.Models.Booking", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("BookingID")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("int")
                        .UseIdentityColumn();

                    b.Property<int>("ClassLevel")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.Property<DateTime>("FromDate")
                        .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                    b.Property<string>("FromDestination")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<DateTime>("ToDate")
                        .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                    b.Property<string>("ToDestination")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<int>("TravelClass")
                        .HasColumnType("int");

                    b.HasKey("BookingID");

                    b.ToTable("Booking");
                });
```

-------------Update--------------

[image]

Comment: Did you change anything from string to datetime and not do a migration. What is the table definition?

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty new. I'm gonna add the table definition that was made from an "add-migration". I hope maybe that's helpful

Comment: I just ran a "add-migration addBookingToDatabase" and that is the newest

Comment: Can you go into sql server or what ever you using and get the actual table definition. I am interested in what the actual types are in the database.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the table definition

Comment: You are specifying column type as `datetime2` but it is stored as `nvarchar(max)` in the database which is odd. Maybe try with normal `datetime` and check if it works

Comment: Actually @TheGeneral. I realize now where you are getting at. You made me realize that my table definitation is wrong. The DateTime columns from C# are saved as nvarchar in the database, and hence the cast error. If you can put up so I can mark it as a solution, I'll do that. Maybe just explain the error so that others in the future will see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is error is likely caused by a mismatch between the types in your database, and the types of your model.

Note : this can have many causes, depending on whether this is code first, newer .net core, forgetting to do a migration or ModelBuilder misdirection.

The easiest fix is to make sure you have run the latest migration and updated the database, your model builder is correct. or that simply your data matches your types

Comment: I deleted the database and re-ran "add-migration ...". My problem was that I changed a type from string to DateTime, but in the database this type was still of type string (nvarchar) instead of date type, wich caused the error

Answer (score 0):

You have a really strange code, in your action, it reminds me a data reader, looks like you are trying to add an item from `IQueryable` to `IList`.

Try this

```
List<Booking> list = _airPortContext.Booking.ToList();
```

Comment: Good point, but not the answer to the question